# Opposite of dcast

Tags: r, reshape

The idea is to convert a frequency table to something geom_density can handle (`ggplot2`).

Starting with a frequency table

```
> dat <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), y = c("c", "c", "d", "d", "d"))
> dat
  x y
1 a c
2 a c
3 b d
4 b d
5 b d
```

Use dcast to make a frequency table

```
> library(reshape2)
> dat2 <- dcast(dat, x + y ~ ., fun.aggregate = length)
> dat2
  x y count
1 a c     2
2 b d     3
```

How can this be reversed?  `melt` does not seem to be the answer:

```
> colnames(dat2) <- c("x", "y", "count")
> melt(dat2, measure.vars = "count")
  x y variable value
1 a c    count     2
2 b d    count     3
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can use any aggregate function, you won't be able to reverse the `dcast` (aggregation) without knowing how to reverse the aggregation.

For `length`, the obvious inverse is `rep`. For aggregations like `sum` or `mean` there isn't an obvious inverse (that assumes you haven't saved the original data as an attribute)

Some options to invert `length`

You could use `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat2,.(x), summarize, y = rep(y,count))
```

or more simply

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat2[c('x','y')], rep, dat2$count))
```

Comment: What about `dat2[rep(row.names(dat2), dat2$count), 1:2]`?

Comment: If you make that comment an answer I'll accept it.  There's always a harder way to do something in R, isn't there?

Comment: @mnel, neither of those work for me.  Apologies if I'm missing something basic, but the first one's error is `Error in NextMethod() : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'`, the other's is `Error in rep.default(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'times' argument`.  Rep is, indeed, the obvious solution but it doesn't seem to be very good at replicating whole rows of data frames.

Comment: @nacnudus they work on your example.